# SoapUI raw request not showing JSON body

Tags: soapui

This question is for SoapUI 5.2.1 community edition:

I have a POST request with JSON body that contains variables.

[image: SoapUI JSON parameters]

I was always able to verify that these parameters take proper values by clicking on "Raw" tab to view the request as it went or will be sent to the server.

Today I found that I no longer see this and only see the headers.

[image: missing JSON in raw request view]

What could be the problem and how can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Check in the `SOAPUI Preferences` panel that your request size doesn't exceed the `Size of Raw Request Message to Show:` property and has `Wrap content in Raw Message Viewers` property checked in `UI Settings` tab.

Open `File > Preferences` in menu (<kbd>CTRL + ALT + P</kbd>) and check this values:

[image]

Finally as @AlexE says in the comment, save preference using in the menu `File > save preferences` and restart SOAPUI.

I also want to advice that I saw a wrong behavior with this, like you I remember that before my requests are shown in the `raw` viewer but now I try it a first with a request that doesn't exceed this values however it was not shown in the  `Raw` viewer, however after increase the value and check the parameter it starts to work again...

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks again @albciff for helping out. For anyone else out there who is stuck with the same thing - I finally got it to display again by changing the values as outlined above, ticked the check-box, saved settings by going to File > Save Preferences and then restarted SoapUI.

Comment: For anyone wondering if this is still relevant. I had the same issue in 5.4.0 and changing these values and restarting does still fix the issue.

Comment: I tried in SoapUI5.6.0 and this did not help. Can you please help?

Answer (score 5):

Another solution for above problem:

Go to **`File > Preferences > Editor Settings`**  and **select** options:

- **Validate Requests**
- **Validate Responses**

[image]