# SoapUI - JSON Post Body not in RawData

Tags: soapui

If I put application/json and put JSON data, shouldn't it appear in the "Raw" data (of SoapUI 5.2.1)?  I have changed the URL in screenshots below.  Getting same result with the real URL.
[image]

[image]
Results after clicking the send button, and showing the "Raw" tab on the left.  I'm thinking that the JSON I typed in is not being sent.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502377/soapui-raw-request-not-showing-json-body

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SoapUI raw request not showing JSON body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502377/soapui-raw-request-not-showing-json-body)