# org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException while working with WSSE Security Service in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, wsse

I am working on WSSE Security Service and trying to apply load on the load using JMeter.

Followed the below steps:

1. First executed the WSSE Security service request in SoapUI.
2. Now using JMeter proxy in SoapUI recorded the WSSE Security request date using JMeter recorder.
3. Added 'SOAP Message Username Token' pre-processor to HTTP REQUEST and passed the username and password.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DztkJ.png)
4. Provided the necessary data to the request and on hitting the run time is displaying with below exception.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAOsN.png)

Can someone please help me on the above that how can I work with WSSE Security Service in JMeter

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're not sending the same request as SoapUI does, i.e. protocol, host or path mismatch.

You can inspect the raw requests originated from:

- [SoapUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502377/soapui-raw-request-not-showing-json-body)
- And JMeter, you will need to [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for HttpCompoments by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

  ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
  ```

  you will be able to see full network communication in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Once you figure out what are the differences and amend JMeter configuration to send the same request as SoapUI does the error should go away.

Comment: I had cross checked the original raw request and compared to that of request sent in JMeter and found that both are same.